# Word game importing TXT file

Tags: java

How would I go about setting up a point scoring Scrabble type game that only scans words in a word document. So, in the following code I would have a text file with 30 different words and then I wouldn't need a println of all the lines in the file with the points per work i.e racecar is 11 points

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Scrabble {

    private String word;

    Scrabble(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    int getScore() {

        Map<Character, Integer> lettersMap = new HashMap<>();
        String lettersCap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < lettersCap.length(); i++) {
            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'A' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'E' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'I' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'O' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'U' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'L' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'N' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'R' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'S' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'T') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 1);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 1);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'D' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'G') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 2);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 2);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'B' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'C' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'M' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'P') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 3);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 3);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'F' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'H' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'V' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'W' ||
                    lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Y') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 4);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 4);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 5);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 5);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'J' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 8);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 8);
            }

            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Q' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Z') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 10);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 10);
            }

        }

        int totalValue = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {

            totalValue += lettersMap.get(word.charAt(j));
        }

        return totalValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: for a list of words defined in a txt file, you want to calculate the score. Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

Fill the Map once and use read from the file, I guess every line has only one word.

You can read the file from **Files#lines** and loop over every line and count the score of every word

```
public class Scrabble {

    private static Map<Character, Integer> lettersMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        fillMap();
    }

    private static void fillMap() {
        String lettersCap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < lettersCap.length(); i++) {
            if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'A' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'E' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'I'
                    || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'O' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'O' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'U'
                    || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'L' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'N' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'R'
                    || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'S' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'T') {

                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 1);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 1);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'D' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'G') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 2);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 2);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'B' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'C' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'M'
                    || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'P') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 3);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 3);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'F' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'H' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'V'
                    || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'W' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Y') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 4);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 4);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 5);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 5);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'J' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 8);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 8);
            } else if (lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Q' || lettersCap.charAt(i) == 'Z') {
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.charAt(i), 10);
                lettersMap.put(lettersCap.toLowerCase().charAt(i), 10);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int readFileAndGetScore(String fileName) {
        int result = 0;
        Files.lines(new File(fileName).toPath()).forEach(wordInLine -> {
            result += getScore(wordInLine);
        });
        return result;
    }

    private static int getScore(String word) {
        int totalValue = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            totalValue += lettersMap.get(word.charAt(j));
        }
        return totalValue;
    }
}
```

---

`main` function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "data.txt";
    int totalScore = Scrabble.readFileAndGetScore(fileName);
    System.out.println(totalScore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The readability of your code is not really good and has a lot of more or less code duplicates.

Since you were asking about a good way to set up the scoring system of your class, I'd suggest that you initialize it only once and not each time your scoring-method is called. That means you should create a static Map and use a static initializer.

```
class Scrabble {
    private static final Map<Character, Integer> POINTS_FOR_LETTER = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        addLettersWithPoints("AEIOULNRST", 1);
        addLettersWithPoints("DG", 2);
        addLettersWithPoints("BCMP", 3);
        addLettersWithPoints("FHVWY", 4);
        addLettersWithPoints("K", 5);
        addLettersWithPoints("JX", 8);
        addLettersWithPoints("QZ", 10);
    }

    private static void addLettersWithPoints(String chars, Integer points) {
        for (char nextLetter : chars.toCharArray()) {
            POINTS_FOR_LETTER.put(nextLetter, points);
            POINTS_FOR_LETTER.put(Character.toLowerCase(nextLetter), points);
        }
    }

    private static int getScore(String word) {
        int score = 0;
        for (char nextLetter : word.toCharArray()) {
            score += POINTS_FOR_LETTER.get(nextLetter);
        }
        return score;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String word : Arrays.asList("Test", "Racecar", "PhysicsquestionWithXAndY")) {
            System.out.println(word + " -> " + getScore(word));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get the score for a word by calling the `getScore()`-method as shown in the `main`-method.